AWS Managed AWS apache flink application writes to kinesis output stream, but kinesis monitoring doesnt show any updates in graph
We are trying to capture some data using kinesis as input and output stream using AWS Managed apache flink as per steps in https://github.com/aws-samples/pyflink-getting-started/tree/main/getting-started
The deployed app works fine in the sense that we are not getting any errors and the log shows successfull insertion of data into the output stream, however the python code exits immediately and I assume because of that we do not see any graphs in the output stream monitoring.
{
    "applicationARN": "arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:eu-west-2:874142760928:application/MyPythonFlinkApp",
    "applicationVersionId": "17",
    "locationInformation": "org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:124)",
    "logger": "org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver",
    "message": "INFO:__main__:Table environment created successfully.\nINFO:__main__:Application properties loaded successfully.\nINFO:__main__:Creating source table input_table with stream ExampleInputStream in region eu-west-2\nINFO:__main__:Source table created successfully.\nINFO:__main__:Creating sink table output_table with stream ExampleOutputStream in region eu-west-2\nINFO:__main__:Sink table created successfully.\nINFO:__main__:Data insertion statement executed.\n",
    "messageSchemaVersion": "1",
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "threadName": "Flink-DispatcherRestEndpoint-thread-4"
}


The python code exits immediately
{
    "applicationARN": "arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:eu-west-2:874142760928:application/MyPythonFlinkApp",
    "applicationVersionId": "17",
    "locationInformation": "org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:127)",
    "logger": "org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver",
    "message": "--------------------------- Python Process Exited ---------------------------",
    "messageSchemaVersion": "1",
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "threadName": "Flink-DispatcherRestEndpoint-thread-4"
}

Below is our code which handles the output table environment using pyflink, this has been tested in local and we get the streaming output as expected in local
from pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, TableEnvironment
import os
import json
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# 1. Creates a Table Environment
try:
    env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
    table_env = TableEnvironment.create(env_settings)
    logger.info("Table environment created successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Failed to create table environment: %s", e)
    raise

statement_set = table_env.create_statement_set()

APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "/etc/flink/application_properties.json"  # on kda

is_local = (
    True if os.environ.get("IS_LOCAL") else False
)  # set this env var in your local environment

if is_local:
    # only for local, overwrite variable to properties and pass in your jars delimited by a semicolon (;)
    APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "application_properties.json"  # local

    CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    logger.info("Current directory: %s", CURRENT_DIR)
    try:
        table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string(
            "pipeline.jars",
            "file:///" + CURRENT_DIR + "/lib/flink-sql-connector-kinesis-1.15.2.jar",
        )
        logger.info("Local pipeline jars set successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Failed to set local pipeline jars: %s", e)
        raise


def get_application_properties():
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH):
            with open(APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH, "r") as file:
                contents = file.read()
                properties = json.loads(contents)
                logger.info("Application properties loaded successfully.")
                return properties
        else:
            logger.error('A file at "%s" was not found', APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH)
    except Exception as er:
        logger.error("Failed to load application properties: %s", er)
        raise


def property_map(props, property_group_id):
    try:
        for prop in props:
            if prop["PropertyGroupId"] == property_group_id:
                return prop["PropertyMap"]
        logger.error("Property group id %s not found in properties.", property_group_id)
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error("Failed to map properties: %s", err)
        raise


def create_source_table(table_name, stream_name, region, stream_initpos):
    logger.info("Creating source table %s with stream %s in region %s", table_name, stream_name, region)
    return """ CREATE TABLE {0} (
                ticker VARCHAR(6),
                price DOUBLE,
                event_time TIMESTAMP(3),
                WATERMARK FOR event_time AS event_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND

              )
              PARTITIONED BY (ticker)
              WITH (
                'connector' = 'kinesis',
                'stream' = '{1}',
                'aws.region' = '{2}',
                'scan.stream.initpos' = '{3}',
                'format' = 'json',
                'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
              ) """.format(
        table_name, stream_name, region, stream_initpos
    )


def create_sink_table(table_name, stream_name, region):
    logger.info("Creating sink table %s with stream %s in region %s", table_name, stream_name, region)
    return """ CREATE TABLE {0} (
                ticker VARCHAR(6),
                price DOUBLE,
                event_time TIMESTAMP(3),
                WATERMARK FOR event_time AS event_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND

              )
              PARTITIONED BY (ticker)
              WITH (
                'connector' = 'kinesis',
                'stream' = '{1}',
                'aws.region' = '{2}',
                'sink.partitioner-field-delimiter' = ';',
                'sink.batch.max-size' = '100',
                'format' = 'json',
                'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
              ) """.format(
        table_name, stream_name, region
    )


def create_print_table(table_name, stream_name, region, stream_initpos):
    logger.info("Creating print table %s", table_name)
    return """ CREATE TABLE {0} (
                ticker VARCHAR(6),
                price DOUBLE,
                event_time TIMESTAMP(3),
                WATERMARK FOR event_time AS event_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND

              )
              WITH (
                'connector' = 'print'
              ) """.format(
        table_name, stream_name, region, stream_initpos
    )


def main():
    try:
        # Application Property Keys
        input_property_group_key = "consumer.config.0"
        producer_property_group_key = "producer.config.0"

        input_stream_key = "input.stream.name"
        input_region_key = "aws.region"
        input_starting_position_key = "flink.stream.initpos"

        output_stream_key = "output.stream.name"
        output_region_key = "aws.region"

        # tables
        input_table_name = "input_table"
        output_table_name = "output_table"

        # get application properties
        props = get_application_properties()

        input_property_map = property_map(props, input_property_group_key)
        output_property_map = property_map(props, producer_property_group_key)

        input_stream = input_property_map[input_stream_key]
        input_region = input_property_map[input_region_key]
        stream_initpos = input_property_map[input_starting_position_key]

        output_stream = output_property_map[output_stream_key]
        output_region = output_property_map[output_region_key]

        # 2. Creates a source table from a Kinesis Data Stream
        table_env.execute_sql(
            create_source_table(input_table_name, input_stream, input_region, stream_initpos)
        )
        logger.info("Source table created successfully.")

        # 3. Creates a sink table writing to a Kinesis Data Stream
        table_env.execute_sql(
            create_sink_table(output_table_name, output_stream, output_region)
        )
        logger.info("Sink table created successfully.")

        # 4. Inserts the source table data into the sink table
        table_result = table_env.execute_sql("INSERT INTO {0} SELECT * FROM {1}"
                                             .format(output_table_name, input_table_name))
        logger.info("Data insertion statement executed.")

        if is_local:
            table_result.wait()
        # else:
            # get job status through TableResult
            # logger.info("Job status: %s", table_result.get_job_client().get_job_status())
            # print(table_result.get_job_client().get_job_status())
    except Exception as errr:
        logger.error("An error occurred in the main function: %s", errr)
        raise


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I had to comment out the part for get_job_status as I was getting the error org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: The Job Status cannot be requested when in Web
Submission
And although we dont see any error we are seeing below "exception""
message
Exception type is USER from filter results [UserClassLoaderExceptionFilter -> USER, UserAPIExceptionFilter -> SKIPPED, UserSerializationExceptionFilter -> SKIPPED, UserFunctionExceptionFilter -> SKIPPED, OutOfMemoryExceptionFilter -> NONE, TooManyOpenFilesExceptionFilter -> NONE, KinesisServiceExceptionFilter -> NONE, UserCauseAssignableSdcExceptionFilter -> SKIPPED, UserCauseRegexSdcExceptionFilter -> SKIPPED, UserExceptionStackRegexSdcExceptionFilter -> SKIPPED].
messageSchemaVersion
1
messageType
INFO
threadName
flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21
throwableInformation
org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to kinesis.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 [kinesis.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/3.10.201.157] failed: connect timed out
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1165)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2980)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2947)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2936)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeListShards(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1606)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.listShards(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1575)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.proxy.KinesisProxy.listShards(KinesisProxy.java:519)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.proxy.KinesisProxy.getShardsOfStream(KinesisProxy.java:464)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.proxy.KinesisProxy.getShardList(KinesisProxy.java:337)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.discoverNewShardsToSubscribe(KinesisDataFetcher.java:930)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer.run(FlinkKinesisConsumer.java:312)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:67)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:335)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer.close(FlinkKinesisConsumer.java:421)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.closeFunction(FunctionUtils.java:41)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.close(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:114)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.close(StreamSource.java:124)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.close(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:163)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.closeAllOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:125)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.closeAllOperators(StreamTask.java:997)
at org.apache.flink.util.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:254)
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.AutoCloseableRegistry.doClose(AutoCloseableRegistry.java:72)
at org.apache.flink.util.AbstractAutoCloseableRegistry.close(AbstractAutoCloseableRegistry.java:127)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.cleanUp(StreamTask.java:916)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.lambda$restoreAndInvoke$0(Task.java:935)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:953)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:935)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:746)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:568)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to kinesis.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 [kinesis.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/3.10.201.157] failed: connect timed out
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy40.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1346)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
... 35 more

Below is our IAM policy
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "ReadCode",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:GetObjectVersion"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::ka-app-code-flink-beam-integretion/GettingStarted.zip"
]
},
{
"Sid": "DescribeLogGroups",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"logs:DescribeLogGroups"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:logs:eu-west-2:874142760928:log-group:"
]
},
{
"Sid": "DescribeLogStreams",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"logs:DescribeLogStreams"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:logs:eu-west-2:874142760928:log-group:/aws/kinesis-analytics/MyPythonFlinkApp:log-stream:"
]
},
{
"Sid": "PutLogEvents",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"logs:PutLogEvents"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:logs:eu-west-2:874142760928:log-group:/aws/kinesis-analytics/MyPythonFlinkApp:log-stream:kinesis-analytics-log-stream"
]
},
{
"Sid": "ReadInputStream",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "kinesis:",
"Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-west-2:874142760928:stream/ExampleInputStream"
},
{
"Sid": "WriteOutputStream",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "kinesis:",
"Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-west-2:874142760928:stream/ExampleOutputStream"
},
{
"Sid": "VPCReadOnlyPermissions",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:DescribeVpcs",
"ec2:DescribeSubnets",
"ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
"ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions"
],
"Resource": ""
},
{
"Sid": "ENIReadWritePermissions",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
"ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
"ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
"ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
],
"Resource": ""
}
]
}
